# Using the Background Location feature to automatically download new content

Tags: ios, background, core-location

There is something tricky I am willing to do, and I'd like to know if such approach could cause Apple to reject my application: some clients are demanding a feature that automatically downloads new content (content allowed by the Apple terms, nothing illegal or against the TOS) whenever they become available.

However, the background possibilities of iOS are quite limited, and even the "background download" option limits the task to run for up to 10 minutes (apparently). Other users have tried to use background audio with a "dummy" sound to keep the application alive and do infinite tasks, but this approach is known to cause Apple to reject the app.

What I am thinking to do is to use Core Location instead of background audio. This approach works fine, despite of consuming much more battery power due to continuous use of the GPS hardware. It is worth mentioning that my application already uses CoreLocation for other "real" stuff.

I'd like to know if anybody has experience with such approach, or if it's sure that my app will be rejected if I choose this path.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the iOS 5 beta release notes.

Comment: jtbandes, which part? I read the release notes but could not figure out what you meant. Thanks

Comment: iOS 5 has a [Newsstand](http://www.apple.com/ios/ios5/features.html#newsstand) feature. The details are still under NDA so you should ask at http://devforums.apple.com.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Meanwhile, any idea for the app running on iOS 4.x? My implementation works, the main question right now is if the core location approach could case the app to be rejected.

Comment: There's not really a way to know for sure. But if you're already using Core Location I think your chances might be better.

Comment: I think if you are not using location for anything else, it may get rejected. It's just like how non-music apps using background audio gets rejected. These apps try to play inaudible sound in the background to keep app awake.